# value not passed into if statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the problem that I encountered which i find it weird.
I am trying to get the value that was declared at the start of the webpage in the if statement. However, i get an empty value instead.

When i use echo to print out the value before the if statement and after the if statement, the value is printed out. But when i echo it IN the IF statement, it is empty.

Below is how i declared the value and the place where i want to use it

```
    <?php
    $id=$_POST['eventID'];
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    //some codes here..
    <?php
      if($edit_counter==6)
      {update_event($sdate,$edate,$stime,$etime,$event,$venue,$id);}
    ?>
```

I needed it to update the table based on the ID. But for some odd reasons I can't seem to pass the $id. $id contain value before and after the IF statement. But not inside the IF statement.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Make sure you are not setting the value of `$id` elsewhere in the code.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what is wrong.  Please paste the `update_event` function.

Comment: is the part where the $id isn't printed out in a other file which is required/included?

Comment: Yes, my guess would be something is wrong in the `update_event` function, or something in the `//some codes here` section is affecting the value of `$id`.

Comment: Are you sure you code even gets into the `if` statement, i.e., is `$edit_counter == 6`?

Comment: bfavaretto,
yes the code did enter the IF statement. But the value $id is null inside the IF statement but not other place in the code.

digitaloday,
I thought about that too. So i've did var_dump and echo throughout that section. It all gives the correct value. Except the one i did inside IF statement where it return a null value.

Answer (score 0):

> $id contain value before and after the IF statement. But not inside the IF statement.

Are you sure that the `if` statement returns true and the inner code is being executed?

Also, make sure to use `var_dump` instead of `echo` to debug `$id`, as echo will not show result if `$id` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the variable is accessible by using --> $GLOBALS

try this

```
<?php 
  if($edit_counter==6){
      $GLOBALS $id;
      update_event($sdate,$edate,$stime,$etime,$event,$venue,$id);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Using Globals is not advisable, security-wise.

Comment: thanks for all ur replies,
to jernej the $id isn't printed out inside the same file. the quotes i gave above are all in the same file. I am able to access the update_event. but the value $id isn't pass. The place where i show the declaration is the only place being declared. however, i did use the $id somewhere else in the code. But i've tested that even after that, the value still gets printed. 

to brian_d i did use var_dump. it contains null value inside the IF statement. BUT outside of the IF statement, the value is not null

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.
The problem was I was trying the access the value *after* submitting it again, which will actually make the value `NULL`.

I've used `<input type='hidden'>` to pass the value again.